# Images being displayed as weird characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In this project I'm trying to implement a price list (it's a taxidermy site) So here's what I'm going to do, show you the code

**PriceListController**

```
public partial class PriceListController : Controller
    {

        public PriceListController()
        {
        }


        [CanonicalUrlAttribute("PriceList")]
        [CompressionFilter(Order = 1)]
        [CacheFilter(Duration = 120, Order = 1)]
        public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities context = new GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities();
            var viewModel = new PriceListViewModel() { PriceListAnimals = context.GetAnimalListForPriceList() };
            return View(viewModel);
        }


        [CompressionFilter(Order = 1)]
        [CacheFilter(Duration = 120, Order = 2)]
        public virtual ActionResult List(string animal)
        {
            GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities context = new GodsCreationTaxidermyEntities();

            var viewModel = new PriceListIndexViewModel() { AnimalPrices = context.GetPriceListByAnimal(animal) };
            return View(viewModel);
        }

    }
```

The **index** work fine. Here's Index.aspx

**Index.aspx**

```
<div id="main-content" title="AnimalBox" style="float:none;">
    <%--<%= Html.DropDownList("AnimalList", Model.Animals, "[Select One]", new { @class = "inputDropDown" })%>--%>
    <% Html.DataList(Model.PriceListAnimals).Columns(6).Item(item =>
{
    item.Template(galleryImage =>  
    {%>
        <div style="margin-right:45px; line-height:150%;">
            <span><%= Html.ActionLink(galleryImage.AnimalName,"List",new { @animal = galleryImage.AnimalName }) %></span>
        </div>  

        <%  });

}).Render(); %>
</div>
```

Now we move on to the listing page

**List.aspx**

```
<div class="maintext" id="pricelist">
        <h2 class="sectionHeader">:: Gods Creation Taxidermy : PriceList ::</h2>
             <% Html.DataList(Model.AnimalPrices).Columns(7).Item(item =>
            {
                item.Template(galleryImage =>  
            {%>                
                    <div><%=galleryImage.TypeName %></div>                                
         <%});

    }).Render(); %>
        <% Html.DataList(Model.AnimalPrices).Columns(7).Item(item2 =>
        {
            item2.Template(galleryImage =>  
        {%>

               <div><%=galleryImage.MountPrice %></div>

        <%  });

        }).Render(); %>
    </div>
```

Here's a screenshot of how this is beeing displayed

[Screenshot](http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/466/weirdoutput.png)

If anyone couod hekp I'd surely be grately.

EDIT: By the way the images arent being stored in a DB, just the path, which makes this even more fonfusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved, I have a couple things backwards